# how can select all post relevant to category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can select all posts related to one category in **wordpress** by **mysql query** and echo by json format ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query //try this link

Answer (score 0):

I hope this MySQL will serve your purpose.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p.post_type = 'post'
  AND t.slug = 'your_category_slug'
```

Just replace `your_category_slug` with your category slug, of which category post u want.

Comment: Unfortunately I used your code but not show anything.

Comment: Do you have any published post? and what is the category slug you have given.

Comment: yes i published post and replace category_slug in your cod but not show anything

Comment: Just for test, add any post to `uncategorized` category and pubish it and then rerun the sql code in phpMyAdmin, with slug as `uncategorized`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help you to get data posts from specific category.

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p.post_type = 'post'
  AND t.slug = 'your_category_slug'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT );
?>
```